# Getting undefined value from the json in console angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, ngfor

I have below response from the api

```
 [
  {
    "Cinema_strName": "Cll, Kollam",
    "Cinema_strID": "CEWB",
    "Cinema_strBannerImg": "",
    "cinema_addr": "5th  Kollam",
    "cinema_loc": "<iframe src=\"https://www9550314\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
    "cinema_mob": 0
  },
  {
    "Cinema_strName": "Cs, Kollam",
    "Cinema_strID": "KEWB",
    "Cinema_strBannerImg": "",
    "cinema_addr": "Carlangara, Kollam, Kerala - 691581",
    "cinema_loc": "<iframe src=\"hsen!2sin49\" width=\"600\" height=\"450\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
    "cinema_mob": 0
  }
]
```

I want to get cinema_loc from the api for that I'm doing below code

```
this.common.createAPIService('api/cinemas/List?CityName='+city, '').subscribe((result: any) => {
  if(result.length){
     this.cinema = result;
     this.loc = this.cinema.cinema_loc;      

     console.log(this.loc);


  }else{
      alert('Cinema not found');
  }
```

})

But it gives me undefined value. If I write `this.cinema[0].cinema_loc`. I will get only first response iframe. Please help.

For @nikhil

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="map" *ngFor="let map of html">
    <div [innerHTML]="map"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you want to read / process cinema_loc?

Comment: I want to append iframe in html

Comment: Do you want a specific cinema_loc or display all of them in iframes in your template?

Comment: All the iframes from response

Answer (score 1):

As `this.cinema` can be an array or an object, you will need to iterate over it in case it is an array. As you are trying to append the html, you can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an html string and then append it as per the requirement. Try following

```
let html = this.cinema.cinema_loc;
if(Array.isArray(this.cinema)) {
    html = this.cinema.reduce((a, {cinema_loc}) => a + cinema_loc, "");
}
```

Comment: Not working. For single response I'm getting object if there is multiple that is like above response I'm getting string

Comment: @SagarKodte - Can you share the response in case of single object?

Comment: Just remove second {} from the above response

Comment: @SagarKodte - So you mean you will receive an object and not an array?

Comment: Yes I checked this by using typeof

Comment: @SagarKodte - For that, you can simply place a check. See the edited answer

Comment: Now I did this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.cinema.reduce((a, {cinema_loc}) => a + cinema_loc, "")); to append in html. But it's not coming

Comment: Please check html template for appending html

Comment: @SagarKodte - html is not an array. It is a string.

Comment: So how can I append this in html?

Comment: Simply use {{html}}

Comment: `<div class="col-md-9">{{html}}</div>`

Comment: Nothing happens. Div is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181805/discussion-between-nikhil-aggarwal-and-sagar-kodte).

Answer (score 0):

**`this.cinema`** is an **`array`**, not an object, if you want to access all the elements you need to iterate over them.

to display on Template use ngFor as follows,

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let cineObj of cinema">
      {{ cineObj.cinema_loc }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

if you need only cinema_loc from all the elements, you can try

```
let result = this.cinema.map(a => a.cinema_loc);
```

if you want to generate a HTML out of it use

```
let resultHtml = this.cinema.map(function(cineObj) {
return cineObj.cinema_loc;
}).join(', ');
```

Comment: I want to append as html

Answer (score 0):

There are couple issues in your code -

1. Wrong way to iterate the cinemas array.
2. Sanitizer - angular will be reporting the unsafe html so better to sanitize it before you use it.

## Create the method to sanitize

```
  safeHTML(content) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
  }
```

## In html

```
<div class="map" *ngFor="let map of cinema">
  <div [innerHTML]="safeHTML(map.cinema_loc)"></div>
</div>
```

## Demo

Demo is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iframe-sanitizer